# How can I crossfade divs in one at a time with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to crossfade image divs in succession upon hovering another div. I'm missing something however, as it's not changing the image upon hover and is instead fading in and out the same div. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shzBu/5/).

```js
$('.card').hover(function() {
  var delay = 0;
  $('.fade-m').each(function() {
    var $fade = $(this);
    $fade.find(".front").fadeOut();
    $fade.find(".back").fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $fade.find(".back").fadeOut();
      $fade.find(".front").fadeIn();
    }, delay += 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.fade-m {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.fade {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.front {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}
.back {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="hover-text">
    <h3>hover text</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<span class="fade-m">
       <div class="front">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
       </div>
       <div class="back">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60">
       </div>
    </span>

<span class="fade-m">
       <div class="front">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
       </div>
       <div class="back">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60">
       </div>
    </span>
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what "cross fade" type of effect means to you? I am confused on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you want to change the picture when you hover, and then fade in the new picture?

Comment: Your fiddle works for me, but appears to work better with position:absolute.

Comment: yes I'm looking to fade the image into the other upon hover, and have it stay there, changing them all in succession. it is working but it's really jumpy and I'm wondering how to make the transition smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want, but it doesn't use jQuery, just pure CSS3.  You may need to run the CSS through an autoprefixer if you want to support browsers that don't support unprefixed versions of some of the properties.

```css
.fade-m {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
}
/* Make all transtions on the img last .5 seconds */
.fade-m img {
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
/* place the back img in the same spot as the front img */
.fade-m .back img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
/* Make sure the front img is always on top of the back img */
.fade-m .front img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Change opacity of the front img to 0 on hover */
.card:hover ~ .fade-m .front img {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Delay the transition on hover of the second .fade-m by .5 seconds */
.card:hover + .fade-m + .fade-m img {
  transition-delay: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="hover-text">
    <h3>hover text</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<span class="fade-m">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
  </div>
</span>

<span class="fade-m">
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
  </div>
</span>
```

Cleaner version:

```css
/* Only if you don't have similar in your normalize.css/reset.css */
.card ul { padding: 0; }

.card li {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

/* Make all transtions on the img last .5 seconds */
.card img {
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

/* place images in the same spot and visible */
.card li img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Make sure the front img is always on top of the back img */
.card img:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Change opacity of the front img to 0 on hover */
.card:hover img:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Use this instead if you want the hover to only work on the h3 and not the entire card
.card h3:hover + ul img:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
}*/

/* Delay the transition on hover of the second .fade-m by .5 seconds */
.card:hover li:nth-child(2) img {
  transition-delay: .5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
  <h3>hover text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert! This is almost what I'd like to do, I just want to make it so that once the images fade they stay there, is that possible with keyframes?

Comment: Sure. So on hover you want the back to show and stay there forever, or just until you unhover?  That's even easier as you can just use a transition instead of an animation.

Comment: yes just until you unhover, exactly, would I just have to remove the crossfadeOut bit?

Comment: I'll switch it to using a transition instead, you don't need keyframes then.

Comment: @jgb Updated answer to fix the flip on hover, and switched to using transition instead of animation.

Comment: You wouldn't need to fade the back img in and out *if* the front and back images were of the same dimensions, but since they aren't, you would see part of the back image around the front if you didn't.

Comment: Oh yes I see what you're saying. They're probably going to be the same size so I can take out that part, awesome. Thank you Robert! :) Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Updated once again changing all images to 50x50 and removing the now not needed back stuff. You might consider removing the `.back`,`.front`,`.hover-text` divs unless you need them for something else.  You can even possibly remove the `.text-m` spans and/or move them inside of .card to make things easier for you.

Comment: Added "Cleaner" version which removes all the unnecessary HTML elements and attributes and put the `.fade-m`s into the card itself and change to ul/li.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, nobody is really clear on what exactly it is that you are looking for. I took a shot at it, but it was a shot in the dark at best.

`setTimeout();`
is non-blocking, so it will not delay the execution of a loop or iterator like you have it in your original code. You have to wrap the function to execute in the setTimeout() or setInterval() and stop it when you reach the end of the list of items.

Here's what I came up with based on what I think you are wanting: 
http://jsfiddle.net/shzBu/11/

Let me know if that's the effect you were looking for.

**EDIT - I misunderstood what you wanted**

 Check out this site for crossfading CSS3 transitions! http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/